# Segfault error when doing "Object = object" of same class

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

First, what i want to do is to resize a class' array when it's full by doing a "object++" but
I got a "Segmentation fault(core dumped)" error when executing a C++ program. The problem is inside the operator++ overloading method. It's supposed to copy the contain of the first array in a temporary object (the operator= overloading is already done and works well), then to change the height and width of the array, and finally copy again the temporary object inside the object which is returned. When i comment "*this = *tmpPlateau ;" the array is resized but the contain is not copied.  the Here is the code :

```
Plateau& Plateau::operator++() {

      // New sizes
      int newHauteur = this->height + 2 ; 
      int newLargeur = this->width + 2 ; 

      // Tableau temporaire avec le contenu du plateau actuel
      Plateau* tmpPlateau = this ;      

      // Actualisation des dimensions 
      this->height = newHauteur ; 
      this->width = newLargeur ;

      this->plateau = new Etat*[height] ; 
      for (int i = 0; i < height; i++) {

        plateau[i] = new Etat[width] ;

      }

      *this = *tmpPlateau ;     

      return *this ;
}
```

The operator= overloading method :

```
Plateau& Plateau::operator=(const Plateau& tab) {

      this->plateau = new Etat*[height] ; 
      for (int i = 0; i < height; i++) {

            this->plateau[i] = tab.plateau[i] ; 

       }

       Plateau(height, width) ;
}
```

Comment: I doubt we'll be able to help you without seeing your `operator=`.

Comment: This is not the post-increment operator (`object++`), but the pre-increment (`++object`).

Comment: Why not use `std::vector`?

Comment: I edited my post and added my operator= method code. Btw, it's a school mini-project and we are asked to use an array :/ but, i prefere using std::vector because it's much easier

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is twofold.

Firstly, `tmpPlateau` is not a separate object. It's just another pointer to `*this`:

```
  Plateau* tmpPlateau = this ;
```

Consequently, the following calls `operator=()` with `*this` as its argument:

```
  *this = *tmpPlateau ;
```

I suspect the crash is because your `operator=()` doesn't handle self-assignment correctly.

However, the real problem is that `tmpPlateau` needs to hold a *copy* of the object rather than a *pointer* to it.

Finally, you'd find it much easier to implement your class if you used `std::vector` instead of an array. This would make it much easier to grow `plateau`.

Comment: Oh ... i see. So it's just like this the values don't really change because tmpPlateau is inside the class too ? Btw, i wanted to use std::vector too, it's so much easier. But it's a school mini-project and we are asked to use an array :/